# How do I evade earthquake attacks from bosses?

Tags: a-hat-in-time

I've seen an attack in a lot of the bosses where the boss slams into the ground and creates a shockwave. It wouldn't be much of a problem to dodge, but the problem is that I get flung in the air and have no control over where I land. I've learned to dodge single shockwaves by using the ice hat to get back on the ground, but this doesn't help much for attacks that make multiple at once.

Is there something that I'm missing about these attacks, or am I best off fine-tuning the ice hat approach?

> The bosses with this attack are the Conductor, DJ Grooves, the toilet of doom, the Snatcher, and Mustache Girl.

Answer (score 1):

Is "jump" too obvious an answer?  You won't be flung if you're not on the ground when the shockwave activates, and you can stay in the air for a fairly long time with the jump-dash-jump bit.  For multiple shockwaves, sometimes swift single hops can get you both in the air for the initial fling and over the shockwaves that approach from earlier attacks.

Of course, some bosses have very little telegraphing, but I suppose that's the challenge.

Comment: By the way, are there any DLC bosses with the shockwave attack?

Comment: @Nissa The boss rematches in Death Wish mode still have shockwave attacks. But the two new finale chapters do not.